Double click to maximize window in VSCode
In VSCode, through configuration or via some extension, I was wondering if it would be possible to make it so that double-clicking on the tab with the file name being edited maximizes it.

It already does that (?). When i double click the tab-register it "maximizes". Or what do you mean by maximizing?

Yes, that's it. In other editors like Eclipse, when you're editing a source file, double-clicking on the file name at the top in its tab maximizes it. But in VSCode, at least mine, that doesn't happen.

I must've set this some time ago and forgot it wasnt a default setting.
There is a Setting "workbench.editor.doubleClickTabToToggleEditorGroupSizes", search for it in the settings and set it to "maximize":
"workbench.editor.doubleClickTabToToggleEditorGroupSizes": "maximize"


I followed your instructions but it's not working for me, it's strange. I'll settle for using CTRL-B, which achieves the same effect. Thanks anyway.

Ohh thats what you mean by maximizing? You want the sidebar to hide?
Maximizing in VSC means, that if you have two tab groups (Split View of 2 Tabs showing side to side) and double click on a tab, that one tab group gets maximized (the other one is hidden). https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/updates/1_84/maximize-editor-group.gif
